# FindWindowEx Windows API returns nothing in AutoIt

Tags: autoit, findwindow, findwindowex

I'm using the following code to return handle for a open file dialog box shown from Notepad.

```
Global $Result = DllCall("User32.dll", "HWND", "FindWindowExA", "HWND", WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Notepad]"), "HWND", Null, "STR", "#32770", "STR", "Open")
ConsoleWrite("FindWindowEx Return Value: " & String($Result[0]) & @CRLF)
```

This always returns `0x00000000`, but given parameters seems correct.

Why does this function return nothing here?

**UPDATE**

The following syntax worked, but I still can't specify the parent window:

```
Global $Result = DllCall('User32.dll', 'HWND', 'FindWindowExW', 'HWND', Null, 'HWND', Null, 'WSTR', '#32770', 'WSTR', 'Open')
```

This finds every dialog box (Paint, WordPad etc.) , but I only want to get the handle to dialog box with parent as Notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single API to restrict the search to just Notepad.  You will have to enumerate all available `#32770` windows, looking for ones that belong to a Notepad process, until you find the one you are looking for.

To enumerate the windows, you can use either:

- [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx), filtering in the callback function using [`GetClassName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx) and [`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx).
- [`FindWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500.aspx) in a loop, initially setting `hwndParent=0` and `hwndChildAfter=0`, and then setting `hwndChildAfter` to the last found window on each subsequent call.

To test if a given window belongs to Notepad, you can:

1. use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to get the window's owning process ID.
2. then use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to open a handle to the process.
3. then use [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217.aspx), or [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919.aspx) to retrieve the path and filename of the EXE that created the process.
4. check if the filename is `notepad.exe` and the path is the Windows system folder.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong here?

Open `notepad.exe` first, type some text without saving, attempt to close notepad but leave resulting dialog (`CLASS:#32770`, asking so save) opened. Example, as per [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm) (untested, no error-checking):

```
Global Const $g_sWnd = '[TITLE:Notepad; CLASS:#32770; INSTANCE:1]'
Global Const $g_hWnd = WinGetHandle($g_sWnd)

ConsoleWrite($g_hWnd & @CRLF)
```

Change `TITLE:Notepad` as required (to notepad's file-open dialog-box title).

Comment: Still returns null, I can use `WinGetHandle('#32770]')`, but it retrieves Task Manager's and IDM's handles randomly....... :-|

Comment: @GTAVLover Adjusted.

Comment: I tested, the problem is open file dialog boxes opened by many programs has the same title "Open", so If there are any other program has "Open" dialog box opened, this returns it also.........I want this to be notepad's one only......Unfortunately it's not "Open - Notepad"....... :-(  That's why I tried using `FindWindowEx`.) What's your point on API call not recognizes the parent handle?